# Resource Monitor with custom emails

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a way to notify non-AccountAdmins when the account is close to a credit threshold? maybe an email list. Does it need to be a scheduled task?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Resource monitor notifications can be set sent to DL's.

Comment: sorry.  i am very new to snowflake.  what do you mean by DL?

how do i set it up to notify other users? i am not seeing an option in the `do notify` section of the resource montior ddl.

Comment: You can create an alias which would contain multiple mail address and set this alias email Id in the profile for one of the account admin user.

Comment: ah so setup a distribution list as an administrator email.  got it.  Thanks for your help Srinath

Answer (score 0):

Sharing the approach I did:

1. I created a new user MY_INTEGRATION_USER, using the Slack channel email.
2. Verified the email (by receiving it on the channel).
3. And set this user as the NOTITFY_USER of the SF Resource Monitor:

   alter resource monitor RM_WH_X set notify_users = (MY_INTEGRATION_USER);